# Are identifiers separate tokens only in select cases?

Tags: c, token

> **1. Lexical Pitfalls**:
>
> For another example, consider this statement:

```
if (x < big) big = x;
```

> Each non-blank character in this statement is a separate token,
> except for the if keyword and the two instances of the identifier big.
>
> In fact, C programs are broken into tokens twice....

— From [C Traps and Pitfalls, Andrew Koenig](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/40/docs/CTrapsAndPitfalls.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjU_M224L_9AhXkTqQEHTXbA8kQFnoECBgQAQ&usg=AOvVaw29gdKbxYzIt7bRglrciAIg).

---

My question is: Why is the `if` keyword and the two instances of the identifier `big` not separate tokens? What are they?

Comment: `if` and `big` are separate tokens. Separate characters `i`, `f`, `b`, `i`, `g` aren't tokens here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text means to say "every character in this expression is a token, except the characters used to form `if` and `big`". In case of `if` then `if` is a token, but not the characters `i` and `f` respectively.

That is, this expression consists of the tokens `if`, `(`, `x`, `<`, `big`, `)`, `big`, `=`, `x`, `;`.

Comment: This might be more relevant in other situations related to parsing rules, such as for example `i+++1` where something informally known as "the maximal much rule" parses this left to right looking for the longest sequence that forms a valid preprocessing token. It will come up with `i`, `++`, `+`, `1`, so this expression is equivalent to `i++ + 1` and not `i + ++1`.